# Calculating radius using tangent point and center point

Tags: circles

I got 2 coordinates which are given to me, they can be random. One is a tangent point coordinate and the other is center point coordinate.

I would like to get the radius of the circle using these 2 points. How would I do that? Is there a formula or something I have forgotten about?

Comment: use the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: is the _tangent point_ the intersection of the tangent and the circle?

Comment: @PeteLangshaw Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the centre $(x_1,y_1)$ and a point on the circumference of the circle $(x_2,y_2)$ then using the general form of a circle in the Cartesian plane$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=r^2$$
and calculating the radius using the distance formula
$$r=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$
we would get
$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2$$
which can be expanded and simplified if required.

Comment: Thank you, that works, just needed the second formula and could calculate the radius which I needed